# I have one NIC with two conflicting IPs. Fix?

Tags: dhcp, ip-address, raspbian

I searched for my problem, and although there are similar questions none guided me in the correct direction. Sorry if it looks like a duplicate question.

I have a LAN behind my ISP modem, routed by a TP-Link TL-WR941ND; DHCP server is up but I have some addresses reserved. I list these here:

- Raspberry Pi (ethernet) -> 192.168.0.100
- Macbook Pro (wifi) -> 192.168.0.101
- Xiaomi phone (wifi) -> 192.168.0.102
- 2nd laptop (wifi) -> 192.168.0.111
- Motorola phone (wifi) -> 192.168.0.112 
  (as you can see, I jumped to .111 in case I want to add more devices of my own, .111 and .112 are devices from other members of the family).

Now the problem, I see in the DHCP client list that the Raspberry is correctly listed as "Permanent" while the Xiaomi phone has a lease countdown with address 192.168.0.103 (should be .102). I could reserve .103 for the phone and call it a day, but I don't want to have this mess in the DHCP list and also want to avoid future conflicts in the network. I give all the info I could collect here:

I launched arp-scan from the Macbook:

```
$sudo arp-scan -I en0 -l

Interface: en0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.9 with 256 hosts
192.168.0.1     [TP-Link MAC]       TP-LINK TECHNOLOGIES CO.,LTD.
192.168.0.100   [Pi MAC]            Raspberry Pi Foundation ####<<<<----?????
192.168.0.102   [Pi MAC]            Raspberry Pi Foundation ####<<<<----?????
192.168.0.104   [guest phone MAC]   (Unknown)
192.168.0.103   [Xiaomi phone MAC]   Airgo Networks, Inc.

621 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.9: 256 hosts scanned in 1.862 seconds (137.49 hosts/sec). 5 responded
```

On the Pi, I run ip address:

```
$ip a show eth0

 2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
 link/ether b8:27:eb:0a:ec:42 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
 inet 192.168.0.100/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0        ####<<<<----????
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
 inet 192.168.0.102/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global secondary eth0  ####<<<<----????
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
 inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe0a:ec42/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And on the Pi /etc/network/interfaces:

```
$cat /etc/network/interfaces

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d: source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp       ####<<<----- seems ok, right?

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

The ARP list on the router does not have any MAC bounded/linked.

I honestly don't know what's going on. I assume the Raspberry is doing weird stuff but sincerely I'm neither a Linux expert nor a sysadmin I'm a little bit lost.

Any idea what could be going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is probably more than one problem in your setup.  You should start by making sure that your static IPs are not in the DHCP range.

Comment: There are no static IPs, not that I'm aware of at least. If you meant the reserved addresses (192.168.0.100/101/etc) they are assigned by the DHCP server in a reserved basis but assigned in the same way that other DHCP addresses. If you're talking about something else, sorry, could you explain a little bit more? Thanks.

Comment: In that case, there must be a problem in those reserved addresses on the router, but I suspect the Xiaomi phone also has a configuration error as it answers wrongly to the ARP request.

Answer (score 2):

Try releasing the DHCP lease from the rPi:
`# dhclient -r eth0`

Then request another address:
`# dhclient eth0`

Comment: After release and request, ip addr shows that 192.168.0.102 has gone as secondary IP. That's great. However, I reset the router (to clean the DHCP client lists and restore each client to their address) and then ip addr shows once again both 192.168.0.100 and 192.168.0.102 as preferred addresses.

How is that possible?

Comment: This answer pointed me out in the right direction. However, it's not exactly the answer to my problem. The answer below. Many thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 0):

Mark pointed me out in the right direction but it wasn't exactly the problem there. The solution is as follows:

The dhcpcd.conf file in /etc/ in the RPi showed the following (among other things):

```
# A hook script is provided to lookup the hostname if not set by the DHCP
# server, but it should not be run by default.
nohook lookup-hostname
::: interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.102/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

This snippet pushes a request for the address 192.168.0.102 as preferred IP when the DHCP server isn't running or it's faulty; between router reboots the script kicks in and it requests for 192.168.0.102; only when the router finishes booting up the DHCP server wakes up and leases 192.168.0.100, but can't negotiate 192.168.0.102 because was already taken as preferred by the RPi. RPi ended up with two IPs, one leased by the DHCP server in the router, another claimed by the DHCP client on the Pi itself.

Commenting the snippet and rebooting fixed everything.